# How to repeat promise chain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I am bilding pet project in React, and faced an asynchronous problem. I have a promise chain,it works, but only once. Need to repeat it for a certain amount of time without stopping. I tried to wrap a promise with setInterval, but, it doesn't work as intended.What approach to use here?

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve()
        }, 3000);
    }).then(() => {
        props.changeBreathText('Exhalation')
    }).then(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            props.changeBreathText('Inhale')
        }, 4000);

    })
```

Comment: you can't repeat a promise - it's a one-time thing, but you can duplicate the chain by wrapping it in a function - whenever you call a function a new chain will be created.

Comment: Wrap the promise inside a function and call that function inside a setInterval. As @marzelin stated, you are not calling or repeating the same promise but creating a new one each time.

Answer (score 1):

you can't repeat a promise - it's a one-time thing, but you can duplicate the chain by wrapping it in a function - whenever you call a function a new chain will be created.

```js
const props = {
  changeBreathText: console.log
}

const delay = (time) => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, time)
})

/* with promises
const promiseChain = () =>
  delay(3000)
  .then(() =>
    props.changeBreathText('Exhalation'))
  .then(() => delay(4000))
  .then(() => props.changeBreathText('Inhale')

  );

function repeatChain(times, chain) {
  let _chain = Promise.resolve();
  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    _chain = _chain.then(chain)
  }
  return _chain
}
*/

// with async await
async function promiseChain() {
  await delay(3000)
  props.changeBreathText('Exhalation')
  await delay(4000)
  props.changeBreathText('Inhale');
}

async function repeatChain(times, chain) {
  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    await chain();
  }
}

repeatChain(3, promiseChain)
```

Comment: Thanks,bro, it is work.  I will read more about async.